# HashMap Help Needed

Tags: java

> Program 1: You are a runner, and you are in training for a race. You'd like to keep track of all of your times for your training runs. You only like to run around lakes. Here's some example data,

```
Calhoun, 45.15
Calhoun, 43.32
Harriet,  49.34
Harriet, 44.43
Harriet, 46.22
Como, 32.11
Como, 28.14
```

> Please write a program which enables you to enter the names of lakes and times, and store it all of this data in data structure(s). Don't store it in individual variables. Your program should still work if you started running around another lake too (e.g. Cedar or Phalen).
>
> Your program should be able to analyze the data that you have stored, and print your fastest time for each lake you ran around. So, for this data, your program will display

```
Calhoun, 43.32
Harriet, 44.43
Como, 32.11
```

> Your program should use input validation.
>
> You should use methods to organize your program.

This was what I was trying to do by using a `HashMap` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Creating a HaspMap as String for Key and Double for value
        HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        String lakeName;//Variable to store lake name
        double time;//Variable to store time




        while (true){
            System.out.println("What is the lake name: ");
            lakeName = input.next();
            System.out.println("How many minutes did you run: ");
            time = input.nextDouble();
            map.put(lakeName, time);//Addding Lake Name to and time to theHaspMap


            if (lakeName.equalsIgnoreCase("A") || time ==1)//A condition to exit the loop 
                 {
                break;


            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: **Mod note:** let's keep comments civil and constructive - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `HashMap<String, Double>` allows you to store just one result for each lake. If you change it to `HashMap<String, List<Double>>`, you'll be able to store multiple results for each lake, and find the fastest result for a given lake.

Instead of

```
map.put(lakeName, time);
```

you'll have something like :

```
List<Double> times = map.get(lakeName);
if (times == null) {
    times = new ArrayList<Double>();
    map.put(lakeName,times);
}
times.add(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `Map<String, Double>` you need to use a `Map<String, List<Double>>` to store ALL times in of each lake.

When stored, you must retrieve lake times:

```
List<Double> times = map.get("Harriet");
```

And get lower value of the list.

```
Double bestTime = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for (Double time : times) {
    if (bestTime > time) bestITime = time;       
}
```